# Add 2hours to datetime-string in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I get the following string from a webservice, `2014-06-05T10:27:47Z`. I want to add 2hours to this.

I tried to convert it to a date and add the time, but it doesn't work. Code below:

```
var d = new Date("2014-06-05T10:27:47Z");
d = new Date(d + 2*60*60*1000);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) and [`getHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) methods of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object instead of trying to do it yourself.

```
var d = new Date("2014-06-05T10:27:47Z");

d.setHours(d.getHours() + 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use setHours method:

```
var d = new Date("2014-06-05T10:27:47Z");
var d2 = new Date("2014-06-05T10:27:47Z");
d2.setHours ( d .getHours() + 2 );
```